# VSIX: open browser window

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, vsix

My visual studio extension generates a URL and I want to open it inside the Visual Studio as a new tab.

I could just use `Process.Start()` to open an external browser but this doesn't look good.

I can open files from disk using this method:

```
void OnOpenBrowserWindow(string url)
  {
     if (url != null)
     {
        IVsCommandWindow service = (IVsCommandWindow) this.GetService(typeof (SVsCommandWindow));
        if (service != null)
        {
           string command = string.Format("File.OpenFile \"{0}\"", url);
           service.ExecuteCommand(command);
        }
     }
  }
```

but it doesn't work for URLs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Easiest way is to use [ItemOperations.Navigate()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/envdte.itemoperations.navigate%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) method.

```
var itemOps = Dte.ItemOperations;
itemOps.Navigate("http://bing.com");
```